# 3d C array to 2d

Tags: arrays, c

This code successfully *displays* a 3D array as a 2D array displaying the two layers next to each other but it needs to integrate into a single 2D array? (values 1-9 display as one 3x3 block, values 10-18 display as another 3x3 block but it should be one continuous block of numbers,

*current* display:

```
1 2 3 10 11 12
4 5 6 13 14 15
7 8 9 16 17 18
```

*desired* display:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

program asks for user input and puts them in `arr1[2][3][3]` and then the program should print the values in `arr2[3][6]` but in the right order, I used 1-18 for demonstration purposes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;               //variables for nested for loops
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;
    int arr1[2][3][3];         //array declaration
    int arr2[3][6];            //array declaration
    printf("enter the values in the array: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)   //represents block
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)   //represents rows
        {
            for( k = 0; k < 3; k++)      //represents columns
            {
                printf("the value at arr[%d][%d][%d]: ", i, j, k);
                scanf("%d", &arr1[i][j][k]);
                arr2[d1 + j][d2 + k] = arr1[i][j][k];
            }
        }
        d1 = (d1 + j == 3) ? 0 : d1 + j;
        d2 = (d2 + k == 6) ? 0 : d2 + k;
    }

    printf("printing the values in 2D array: \n");
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr2[j][k]);
            if (k == 6)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to convert it further

Comment: update your question to show desired layout of result in 2D format

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and the desired output. If you hard-code the input into the program by initializing the array elements, then it would be even better.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I fixed it to provide more info :)

Answer (score 0):

The 3D matrix has 2 layers of 3 rows of 3 columns. From the text in the question, it seems you want to convert this object to 3x6 matrix, ie: 3 rows of 6 columns.  The definition `int arr2[3][6]` defines a 6x3 matrix, ie: 3 rows of 6 columns.

To populate the 2D matrix with the desired projection, here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr1[2][3][3];                  // 3D array declaration
    int arr2[3][6];                     // 2D array declaration

    printf("enter the values in the array:\n");
    int d1 = 0, d2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {           // iterate on blocks
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {       // iterate on rows
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {   // iterate on columns
                printf("enter the value of arr[%d][%d][%d]: ", i, j, k);
                if (scanf("%d", &arr1[i][j][k]) != 1)
                    return 1;
                // set the value in the 2D matrix,
                // successive rows are combined left to right
                arr2[d1][d2] = arr1[i][j][k];
                if (++d2 == 6) {
                    d1++;
                    d2 = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("printing the values in 2D array:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            printf("%d ", arr2[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (reading loop elided):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Note that the 3D and 2D arrays defined in the above code have the same values in the same order. You could initialize `arr2` by simply copying the contents of `arr1` as a block after the reading loop:

```
    memcpy(arr2, arr1, sizeof arr1);
```

Another approach is to access the contents of `arr1` as a 2D array via a pointer. You would define `arr2` as a pointer to a 3x6 2D array that aliases the same memory:

```
    int (*arr2)[6] = (int (*)[6])arr1;
```

This way, any modification of the 3D array is immediately visible in the 2D array, and vice versa.

Here is a modified version with this approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr1[2][3][3];              // 3D array declaration
    // define arr2 as a pointer to the rows in arr1
    int (*arr2)[6] = (int (*)[6])arr1;

    printf("enter the values in the array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {           // iterate on blocks
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {       // iterate on rows
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {   // iterate on columns
                printf("enter the value of arr[%d][%d][%d]: ", i, j, k);
                if (scanf("%d", &arr1[i][j][k]) != 1)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("printing the values in 2D array:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            printf("%d ", arr2[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("arr2[0][5] is %d\n", arr2[0][5]);
    arr1[0][1][2] = 100;
    printf("set arr1[0][1][2] = %d\n", arr1[0][1][2]);
    printf("arr2[0][5] is now %d\n", arr2[0][5]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output (reading loop elided):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18

arr2[0][5] is 6
set arr1[0][1][2] = 100
arr2[0][5] is now 100
```

Comment: you're amazing. You explained it so well and I totally understand what you're saying :) thank you so so much! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Ally: you're welcome! You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote all answers that helped you.